# how to skip or ignore data of coulmn when expcted coulmns are higher then headers

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have lines like this

```
id:message:user
 1:hi:admin
 2:im fine :):user1
```

on line 2 there are two separator which means 4 columns so it throws `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First decide what you want to do with bad lines?

if you want to skip them, use additional parameter(s) while reading file using pandas:

```
error_bad_lines=False
```

Code becomes:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("test_data_file.csv", delimiter=":", warn_bad_lines=False, error_bad_lines=False)
```

if you don't want to drop the 'unusual' data (usual case), read the data as rows of string & process each row based on the number of separators as below:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("/home/kiran/test_data_2.csv")
>>> df["id"]= df['id:message:user'].apply(lambda x: x.split(":")[0])
>>> df["message"]= df['id:message:user'].apply(lambda x: x.split(":")[1] if (len(x.split(":"))==3) else x.split(":")[1]+":"+x.split(":")[2])
>>> df["user"]= df['id:message:user'].apply(lambda x: x.split(":")[-1])
>>> df.drop('id:message:user', 1, inplace=True)
>>> df.head(5)
  id     message     user
0  1          hi    admin
1  2  im fine :)    user1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but skipping errors will lose the data

Comment: Then you need to tell the logic how to refine data based on your data pattern.

Comment: I am updating the answer as per the data. This logic varies based on the dataset.

Comment: basicly it is the correct way , but since im dealing with vbulletin hashes it comes like that hash:salt the salt contains all possible chars so whatever the separator is will cause always problem unless using base64 or encoding it , thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the extra separators can only occur in the center column.

So if you read the input line into a string, you can easily find both separators:

- The first separator is the first ':' in the string
- The second separator is the last ':' in the string

Therefore:

- Any part of the string before the first separator should go to the first column
- Any part of the string between the first and the last separator should go into the second column (including all the colons in the message)
- Any part of the string after the last separator should go into the third column

(Please note that this method does not work if there is more than one column which may contain separators.)